# Why do lower type bounds change the variance position?

Tags: scala, generic-variance

The [Scala Language Specification (Section 4.5 on Variance Annotations, p. 44)](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf#page=52)  says

- The variance position of a type parameter is the opposite of the variance position
  of the enclosing type parameter clause.
- The variance position of the lower bound of a type declaration or type parameter
  is the opposite of the variance position of the type declaration or parameter.

Using the first point above, it is easy to see (at least formally) that

```
trait Covariant[+A] {
  def problematic[B <: A](x : B)
}
```

produces the error message

```
error: covariant type A occurs in contravariant position in type >: Nothing <: A of type B
       def problematic[B <: A](x : B)
```

and using the first and the second point it is easy to see that

```
trait Contravariant[-A] {
  def problematic[B >: A](x : B)
}
```

produces the error message

```
error: contravariant type A occurs in covariant position in type >: A <: Any of type B
             def problematic[B >: A](x : B)
```

As I mention, it's easy to see formally (i.e., following the rules for variance annotations) why these errors occur. However, I can not come up with an example illustrating the need for these restrictions. In contrast, it is very easy to come up with examples that illustrate why method parameters should change variance positions, see e.g. [Checking Variance Annotations](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/type-parameterization.html#19.4).

So, my question is the following: Assuming, the two pieces of codes above were allowed, what are the examples of problems that arise? This means, I'm looking for examples [similar to this one](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/type-parameterization.html#19.4) that illustrate what could go wrong in case the two rules cited above were not used. I'm particularly interested in the example involving lower type bounds.

Note that the answer to [Scala type bounds & variance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16925084/scala-type-bounds-variance) leaves this particular question open, whereas the answer given in [The "lower bound" will reverse the variance of a type, but why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391952/the-lower-bound-will-reverse-the-variance-of-a-type-but-why) seems wrong to me.

Edit: I think the first case can be handled as follows (adapting the example cited above). Assume, the following was allowed

```
trait Queue[+T] {
  def head : T
  def tail :  Queue[T]
  def enqueue[U <: T](x : U) : Queue[T]
}
```

Then we could implement

```
class QueueImplementation[+T] extends Queue[T] {
  /* ... implement Queue here ... */
}

class StrangeIntQueue extends QueueImplementation[Int] {
  override def enqueue[U <: Int](x : U) : Queue[Int] = {
    println(math.sqrt(x))
    super.enqueue(x)
  }
}
```

and use it as

```
val x : Queue[Any] = new StrangeIntQueue
x.enqueue("abc")
```

which is clearly troublesome. However, I can not see how to adapt this in order to show that the combination "contravariant type parameter + lower type bound" is also problematic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose we allow for a class to have a type parameter `[-T]` and a method on that class to have `[U >: T]`...

```
for come class hierarchy
Dog <: Mammal <: Animal

class Contra[-X](x: X){
  def problem[Y >: X](y: Y): Y = x // X<:Y so this would be valid
}

val cMammal:Contra[Mammal] = new Contra(new Mammal)

val a:Animal = cMammal problem new Animal // Animal >: Mammal, this is fine
val m:Mammal = cMammal problem new Mammal // Mammal >: Mammal, this is fine
val d:Mammal = cMammal problem new Dog    // (Dog upcasts to Mammal) >: Mammal, this is fine

val cDog:Contra[Dog] = cMammal // Valid assignment

val a:Animal = cDog problem new Animal // Animal >: Mammal, this is fine
val m:Mammal = cDog problem new Mammal // Mammal >: Mammal, this is fine
val d:Dog    = cDog problem new Dog    // AAAHHHHHHH!!!!!!
```

This last line would type check, `cDog problem new Dog` would actually return a `Mammal`. This is clearly not a good thing. Thankfully the type system doesn't actually let us do this.

Q.E.D. contravariant type parameter + lower type bound not a good idea to mix.

I hope this example helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for, but I somehow wasn't able to come up with it myself...

Answer (score 1):

Use the `++` method from `List` to see why the restrictions are needed. Due note, this requires that `++` produce a `List[B]`:

```
 def ++[B](that: GenTraversableOnce[B]): List[B]
```

with a full signature of

```
 def ++[B >: A, That](that: GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, That]): That
```

So why is it important that `[B >: A]`. Well, what if we want to combine something such that

```
 trait Foo
 trait Bar extends Foo
```

and we have a method that has a signature

```
 def op(that: List[Foo], other: Foo): List[Foo] = that ++ List(other)
```

I can pass it a list of type `Bar` but in order to be able to return it as a `List[Foo]` I must make the condition that `Foo >: Bar` so that I can actually do the following

```
 def see(that: List[Bar]): List[Foo] = op(that, myFoo)
```

which essentially is doing a `List[Bar] ++ List[Foo]` to return a type of `List[Foo]` as expressed though a `List[Foo]` type. That is why the flip happens.

Now if I tried to enforce that `Foo <: Bar` I would immediately run into the issue that `List[Bar] ++ List[Foo]` could not return a list of type `Foo` (not to mention having it conflict with the definition above.) It would only ever be able to return a `List` of the least upper bound.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I'm not sure whether I understand it completely, but it does not seem to directly address the issue at hand. You're explaining when the "covariant type parameter + lower type bound" pattern (see e.g. http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/137.html ) is useful, but this does not explain why "covariant type parameter + upper bound" and "contravariant type parameter + lower type bound" are not allowed?

Comment: @godfatherofpolka ok, added some clarification. Does that help?